# Margin causing responsive issue

Tags: css, responsive-design

i am practicing with 3 box for responsive purpose. It works great what I want to do when I dont have margins for the box. But when I add margin the desired result is not happening. Then I have to use percentage like 45% If I want to have two box side by side. But isnt it possible to use 50% that account for the margin as well?

Here are my code. Some explanation if possible will be very much appreciated.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 background-color: lightblue;
}
.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
}
.blue {
 background-color: orange;
 width: 100%
}

.red {
 background-color: red;
}
.green {
 background-color: green;
}

@media  screen and (min-width: 500px) {
 .blue {
  width: 50%;
 }
 .red {
  width: 50%;
 }
 
}

@media  screen and (min-width: 700px) {
 .blue {
  width: 33%;
 }
 .red {
  width: 33%;
 }
 .green {
  width: 33%;
 }
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Testing</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box blue"></div>
  <div class="box red"></div>
  <div class="box green"></div> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes you can use percentage to assign spacing between.

Answer (score 0):

Use Padding with box-sizing, don't use margin.
Use this Html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box blue">
      <div class="blue-bg"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="box red">
      <div class="red-bg"></div>
       </div>
      <div class="box green">
      <div class="green-bg"></div>
       </div>   
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box > div{
    height:100px;
 }
.blue {
    width: 100%
}
.blue-bg{
   background-color: orange;
}

.red-bg {
    background-color: red;
}
.green-bg {
    background-color: green;
}

@media  screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .blue {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .red {
        width: 50%;
    }

}

@media  screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .blue {
        width: 33%;
    }
    .red {
        width: 33%;
    }
    .green {
        width: 33%;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The margin attribute is not an inner part of the div element. However when you set `box-sizing: border-box` then border becomes part of the div element. So, what you can do is set the `border-width` to your desired percent value and set `border-style` to `solid` and `border-color` to background-color that is `lightblue`.

> http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 background-color: lightblue;
}
.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
    border-width: 5%;
    border-color: lightblue;
    border-style: solid;
}
.blue {
 background-color: orange;
 width: 100%
}

.red {
 background-color: red;
}
.green {
 background-color: green;
}

@media  screen and (min-width: 500px) {
 .blue {
  width: 50%;
 }
 .red {
  width: 50%;
 }
 
}

@media  screen and (min-width: 700px) {
 .blue {
  width: 33%;
 }
 .red {
  width: 33%;
 }
 .green {
  width: 33%;
 }
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Testing</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box blue"></div>
  <div class="box red"></div>
  <div class="box green"></div> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are applying margins on a div then it will get applied on the outer part of the div. And because of that reason you need to reduce the width of the box.

If you have 4 boxes in a single row you can distribute 25% width to all 
if you wanted to add margin right of about 1% then you need to decrease 1% width of every div.